# Laravel: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance while trying to populate field in a Edit view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just starting to learn Laravel and while following Laracast "Laravel from scratch" series I got to the point of creating an edit page in which a have to get the id of a product and populate the inputs with existing data, but following the instructions in the video I keep getting the error

> "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance".

ProductController.php

```
public function edit(Product $id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);

    return view('admin.product.edit', compact('product'));
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Edit product</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="/product" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" value="{{$product->name}}">
                    <br>
                    <textarea name="description" id="descriptopn" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Description">{{$product->description}}</textarea>
                    <br>
                    <input type="number" name="price" id="price" min="0.1" step="0.01" placeholder="Price" value="{{$product->price}}">
                    <br>
                    <input type="number" name="stock" id="stock" min="1" step="1" placeholder="Stock" value="{{$product->stock}}">
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If it's any help I'm currently using Laravel v8.22.1 (PHP v8.0.0), and I believe at the time of recording the series, Laracast used Laravel v6.

Edit: Adding table structure.

Migration file:

create_products_table.php

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->float('price');
        $table->integer('stock');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Edit #2: Adding Product Model

Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

//Admin routes
Route::get('/product', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('product', [ProductController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/product/create', [ProductController::class, 'create']);
//Route::get('/product/{article}', [ProductController::class, 'show']);
Route::get('/product/{article}/edit', [ProductController::class, 'edit']);
Route::put('/product/{product}', [ProductController::class, 'update']);
```

**Thank you everyone for your answers** I remember using this same style of logic in Laravel 6 and everything worked, but now I've had issues with Laravel 8, if a get rid of the error message with the suggestions of @ByWaleed and @vozaldi then the inputs in the edit.blade.php don't get populated with the necessary data, Firefox console doesn't show any errors and when using dd() it shows as follows

dd($id):

```
App\Models\Product {#303 ▼
#connection: null
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: false
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: []
#original: []
#changes: []
#casts: []
#classCastCache: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#fillable: []
#guarded: array:1 [▼
   0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

dd($product)

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1184 ▼
    #items: []
}
```

Comment: Can you show me your products table structure?

Comment: Don't think you need the first line in the function because you function parameter will find the product with the given id and you can access the product in the $id variable. So try passing the $id to the view.

Comment: @ByWaleed as your suggestion i commented out the first line and passed the $id to the view, it doesn't give me te error i mentioned above, but it does not populate the inputs with the data asociated to said id. Of course a made the necesary changes to the edit.blade.php and ProductController files.

Comment: Use `findOrFail` instead.

Comment: @SMIftakhairul thank you for your suggestion, but when using findOrFail the error persist.

Comment: Can you show you `Product` model please?

Comment: Can you please dump the $product to confirm the name property exists (just add ```dd($product)``` above the return statement.

Comment: @ByWaleed yes i already added it in the main question.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that. It seems like it's not finding anything with the $id. Could you please dump id and confirm if it  exists in your database. To me it look like it's already finding the product when passed in the parameter.

Comment: @ByWaleed I'm sorry i made a mistake, the first dd() is for $id, and the newly added dd() is for $product. Already edited the original question.

Comment: If this is the route for this edit function then the variable name is incorrect ```Route::get('/product/{article}/edit', [ProductController::class, 'edit']);```.  Article should be renamed to product in the route and function parameter would be $product instead of $id. If that's not the case, can you please clarify what route if pointing to the function because that's the only route pointing to the controller and function.

Comment: @ByWaleed yes you are completly right, the route variable should be  `product` instead of  `article`. I just tested it and that was the problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad that worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you everyone for your time**

All of your answers where very helpful, but it turns out i just made a typo.

In the edit route
`Route::get('/product/{article}/edit', [ProductController::class, 'edit']);`
I wrote `{article}` instead of `{product}` (Both the model and controller where named Product) as stated by @ByWaleed. After making that correction everything works correctly.

As a recomendation for future users, if posible use `Route::resource()` instead of writing each route individually it makes it less likely to make a mistake as te one i did.

Again thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Laravel community.

Here, I can see in your Controller `public function edit (Product $id)` where `$id` is already a Model.

So instead, you should do like this

```
public function edit(Product $product)
{
    return view('admin.product.edit', compact('product'));
}
```

or in older Laravel is done like this

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    return view('admin.product.edit', compact('product'));
}
```

You can debug your codes function `dump()` or `dd()`. For example:

```
public function edit(Product $id)
{
    dd($id); // debug $id and exit

    ...rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but despite i get rid of the error message inputs in edit.blade.php don't get populated with the product data.

Comment: Is there any error message? or have you done any debug?